# MYSQL search for specific word or number in field excluding words or numbers containing those

Tags: php, mysql, regex, wildcard, sql-like

I am searching `welds`.`welder_id` and `welds`.`bal_welder_id` which are lists of unique welder IDs separated by spaces by the users.

The record set looks like `99`,`199`,`99 w259`,`w259 259 5-a`

99,199,259,5-a and w259 are unique welder id numbers

I cannot use the MYSQL INSTR() function by itself as  a search for "99" will pull up records with "199"

Users on each project format their welder IDs a different way (000,a000,0aa) usually to match their customer's records.

I really want to avoid using PHP code for a number of reasons.

To select records with "w259" in the `welder_id` OR in the `bal_welder_id` columns, my query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `welds` 
WHERE `omit`=0 
AND(    (`welder_id`='w259' OR `bal_welder_id`='w259')
     OR (`welder_id` LIKE 'w259 %' OR `bal_welder_id` LIKE 'w259 %')
     OR (`welder_id` LIKE '% w259' OR `bal_welder_id` LIKE '% w259')
     OR (INSTR(`welder_id`, ' w259 ') > 0 OR INSTR(`bal_welder_id`,' w259 ') > 0))
ORDER BY `date_welded` DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

It works but it takes 0.0030 seconds with 1300 test records on my workstation's SSD.

The actual DB will have hundreds of thousands after a year or two.

Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one option is to use [FIND_IN_SET(str, strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) string function, which returns the position of the string `str` in the comma separated string list `strlist`, for example:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

will return 2. Since your string is not separated by commas, but by spaces, you could use REPLACE() to replace spaces with commas. Your query can be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `welds` 
WHERE
  `omit`=0
  AND
  (FIND_IN_SET('w259', REPLACE(welder_id, ' ', ','))>0
  OR
  FIND_IN_SET('w259', REPLACE(bal_welder_id, ' ', ','))>0)
```

The optimizer however cannot to much, since FIND_IN_SET cannot make use of an index, if present. I would suggest you to normalize your table, if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more professional but it takes the same amount of time. The app is up and running so I may have to do a PHP str_replace() to swap commas/spaces before read/write for the next release. Would it be worth it? How would you normalize the table?

Comment: I would have a hard time storing indexes in this field because I don't want to alter "permanent" records. If we change a welder's ID to accommodate new customer's numbering system, We would alter those past records for the last job we did.